# GIT: Erro de permissão no git merge

Tags: git, merge, file-permission

Utilizo Ubuntu.

Ocorre uma coisa estranha. Tenho o projeto principal na branch master e fiz uma nova branch para alterações e testes. Quando crio novos arquivos nessa nova branch fica tudo ok, sem problemas de permissões nem nada.

Verificando e estando tudo ok eu volto para a master e faço um git merge. Ai vem o problema, todos os arquivos que são "trazidos" pelo merge vem sem permissão para modificação. Dai tenho que entrar no terminal e arrumar as permissões.

Isso é normal? Não tem como vir com as permissões corretas?

Obrigado pessoal.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é porque de fato os arquivos estão com as permissões erradas em alguma das branches. Deixe as permissões iguais, faça um commit e tente novamente o merge.

Há também como fazer o Git ignorar o file mode, mas não recomendo. É só rodar `git config core.fileMode false`.